# Usecase needing to Set values to counter in prometheus and not increment

Tags: prometheus

The exporter we wrote queries an external system and gets the value as a total count.
`redshift_scan_query_total 235`

This value increases over time. But the golang client for prometheus does not allow to set values in counter, it only allows to increment.

Also the external system sometimes resets the data and drops these values sometimes as it is an approximate value.

Should i use gauge? Will `increase()` work with Gauge? Gauge will result in multiple metrics in case of restart of the exporter.

How to analyze the total number of queries increased over 1 day using Prometheus for this use case?

Comment: https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/issues/872

Comment: i think need to use Constmetric https://www.robustperception.io/setting-a-prometheus-counter